# How does polymer react to internal content

Tags: polymer

I am experimenting with polymer to see if I can build a mobile version of an application I have already developed in php/mootools

What I want to achieve is a single page application, that when it starts up puts a single image splash screen, whilst in the background it validates the user as a logged in member of an smf forum. If it fails to validate, it will redirect to a login url.  So I am thinking that the body of my index.html page will contain something like this

```
<body>
    <forum-auth forumurl="/forum/authorize.php" login_url="/login" splash="background.png">

      ... lots of content with further polymer elements with access to global variables
      {{token}} and {{user}} which gets returned by a successful logon. the token is a JWT and the user object is application specific.

    </forum-auth>
```

The polymer element definition would go something like this

```
  <template>
      <div id="splash" class="show-splash-screen">
           <img src="{{splash}} />
      </div>
      <core-ajax url="{{forumurl}} handleAs="json" on-core-response={{handleResponse}}></core-ajax>
      <template if="{{token}}">    
          <content></content>
      </template> 
  </template>
```

And some script to tie all that together, which I haven't figured out yet. but which will include the assignment of the ajax response to this.token and this.user and remove the show-splash-screen class from the div which is the splash element.

My question is - is this the correct way to architect a requirement like this -should I invest my time to build this token this way.  I ask, because I am not sure what the reference to "light DOM" means in the documentation and whether effectively embedding the meat of the application as content to this element is the right thing to do.

Or is there a better way to achieve the same sort of thing. Perhaps not including the content, or the flash image or the login-url, and just firing one of two events when the authorization fails or completes (something I am nervous of as it is not declarative).

Comment: I cloned the topeka app from github and ran bower install on it, and it brought in all the dependant components.  This gives a was using core-animated-pages to switch from an initial splash screen to other parts of the app, once the user had logged in.  Whilst it doesn't answer my direct question, it provides a great reference for me to figure some stuff out.

Sadly the core-animated-pages documentation seems broken at the moment